# Send "user input" to a process running a program with exec

Tags: c, input, process, pipe, fork

I am writing a program (in c) to compare the output of two executables. I am in college and would like a nice way to compare the output of my professors code for a project (the behavior of which I need to replicate in my code) to the output of my code. This would be easy if I didn't have to worry about user input.

The basic idea:
My idea for this project is that I would create two additional processes. One of which runs my code and send the output to a file, and runs my professors code and sends the output to a file. Within each process, the program may prompt the user for some input. I do not want to have to manually enter the input during the execution of the main program. I would like one the main program arguments to be the arguments that get passed into each program.

My question:
I will need a way to know precisely when the subprograms are requesting user input, and I need some method by which to send the arguments to each subprogram. I am familiar with communication between processes, but I am not sure how to simulate user input. I would like to be able to use this for all my programming assignments, meaning I do not want to have to modify the code each time I receive a new assignment. Also, I do not have access to the professors code and therefore cannot modify it. I only have access to the executable. What should I do?

Comment: It would be simpler to write a program, fork the process within that program, let the parent process execute your program and the child process your professors' with the same input. Pipe the output in two different files, i.e. _myFile_ and _profFile_ and use [diff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) to compare both outputs.

Comment: yes, I know. My goal is to not have to manually inter user input for BOTH programs. If that's is impossible, I will do it that way.

Comment: Well, why don't you manually type your input **once** in a file, each line containing the user input you would normally type in (_manually_), then start the program and pipe in the input file in your professor's program? i.e. `./myProgramm < inputFile` It does not matter when the program will ask for user input, as it will read from the inputFile.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [expect(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). It should do everything you need.